# ExtJs 4.2 change border color for all combo drop down lists

Tags: css, extjs4, border, extjs4.2

What is the best way to change the border colours of all combobox dropdown lists in an Ext JS application?

Comment: Heard of firebug or the inspect tool in browser?

Comment: Please add some codes have you tried ;).

Comment: @SharathDaniel I can change color using firebug but that class change every component border color. I want permanent solution not temporally. anyway thanks for your feedback

Comment: If the dropdown has another class, add the border color to that.

Comment: Simplified and rewritten question in third person form.

Removed colour tag because this is a border question and does not involves colour problem like mixing colour, converting colour space, colour distortion, or problems like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x-boundlist class I want to change for combo drop down list style change.
After load ext-theme-neptune-all.css i override x-boundlist as bellow

```
.x-boundlist {
   border-color: #3892d3;
}
```